# How to perform OOB migration on PC with no browser?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api, google-api-python-client

Previously I used the following code to authorise the user:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow

def get_authenticated_service( self , args):
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/" + CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary',
      message='client_secrets files is missing')

    credentials = None
    storage = Storage(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/" + "token-oauth2.json")
    credentials = storage.get()

    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
      credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

    self.token = credentials.access_token

    return build('photoslibrary', 'v1',
      http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))
```

(googleapiclient version is 1.6.2)

It was generating the url like `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fphotoslibrary&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&client_id=x.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline`, so I was able to copy it to another device to perform authorization.

Now it returns `400: invalid_request. The out-of-band (OOB) flow has been blocked in order to keep users secure`.

I am reading [the migration doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/oob-migration), but see no solution for my case. What is the current authorization process?